# Use of Jenkins environment variable in directory path

Tags: jenkins, hudson, environment-variables

I'm relatively new to the Jenkins world and I'm having issues with the use of environment variables.

I'm currently running builds from code I check out from a git repository.  I have an environment variable called GIT_BUILD_NUMBER that I pull from the checkout and use successfully in a Windows Batch Command Block:

```
::Build Project
python buildProj.py --branch %Branch% --bin_src %WORKSPACE% --build_number %GIT_BUILD_NUMBER%
```

This executes successfully with the proper git build number.  In the very next "Execute Windows Batch command" block, I simply try to use that same variable in a directory path and this causes the build to fail:

```
J:\builds\%GIT_BUILD_NUMBER%\
```

I've also tried this:

```
J:\\builds\\%GIT_BUILD_NUMBER%\\
```

When I echo this line, I just get:

```
J:\builds\\
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you use set to display your current environment in your batch command, what does it display ?

Comment: I think my issue is syntax -- for example, if I reference the variable this way in the second code block: python script.py %GIT_BUILD_NUMBER% -- it works fine.  It has to be with the way I'm trying to use it in the directory path.